# Magento 2 : responsible code for coupon apply

Tags: magento2, redis

I am using Magento 2.4 EE.

I have created a custom cart rule but the issue i am facing with it is
when the discount is 0 then also it applies to the cart.

So,
I want to know which files are responsible for preventing the coupon code/cart rule to apply when the discount amount of the applied coupon is 0.

I have checked on Magento sales rule module but did not get much clue

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Can you write more about this?

Comment: Can you tell what conditions are you applying while creating the rule ?

Comment: Yes let me update the question

Answer (score 2):

Open the **vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Validator.php** class, Then check the following method:

```
public function process(AbstractItem $item)
```

Now open: **vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/RulesApplier.php**
and check:

```
public function applyRules($item, $rules, $skipValidation, $couponCode)
```

and

```
protected function applyRule($item, $rule, $address, $couponCode)
```

**[Update]**

The following location you have all discount type:

> vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Action/Discount

Open vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/Action/Discount/ToFixed.php and check the following method:

```
public function calculate($rule, $item, $qty)
```

**[Update (2021-07-17)]**

Try to add following code after **$this->applyRule(** in **vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/RulesApplier.php:: public function applyRules($item, $rules, $skipValidation, $couponCode)**

```
if ($item->getDiscountAmount() <= 0 ) {
    continue;
}
```

*Don't write the core, you can create a patch or overwrite that class. It's a bad class which means lots of private property and method of that class.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i need to know where it checks if discount amount is > 0 then rule apply else not.

Comment: Updated, you can try

Comment: I am not sure why it sets in DiscountData if all amount are 0 ?

Comment: Yeah, It's saved all applied rules that are valid for the cart. Don't care about price. You can modify your requirement.

Comment: If you discounted to 0, then you don't need that rule actually.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, what happens is when  coupon to cart & discount amount is 0 then coupon to cart in default magento also.
i can see in quote table.
It should not.

Comment: Yeah. You can see that coupon in quote table and shopping cart because that is valid coupon.

Comment: As I said, If you don't want to apply coupons if the discount is 0, then you need modification.

Comment: Yes, could you please advise what can be the modification ?
just let me know within core files i will move it in module.

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

**Hello below is file and function fire when you apply Coupon Code**

> vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/CouponManagement.php

```
public function set($cartId, $couponCode){}
```

hope it's help you :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i need to know where it checks if discount amount is > 0 then rule apply else not.